# Calculate GPA score in two decimals from multiple grade arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

Need help to validate this code- something is not working in code. I have put this to calculate GPA from multiple arguments

\\

```
import sys

(sys.argv[0])
grades= (sys.argv[1])
 def cal(grades):
     i = 0
     score = 0
     x = {'A':4.0, 'A-':3.66, 'B+':3.33, 'B':3.0, \
    'B-':2.66, 'C+':2.33, 'C':2.0, 'C-':1.66, \
    'D+':1.33, 'D':1.00, 'D-':.66, 'F':0.00}
     if grades !=[]:
         for a in grades:
             score += x[a]
         gpa = score/len(grades)
         return gpa
         print(gpa)
     else:
         return None
         print(None)
 cal(grades)
```

\\

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @RichardKYu - no value getting printed

Comment: @RichardKYu - it worked! Appreciate it. how can I adjust it for multiple input argument? For example: What if input is A, C, B-, F - looking to get calculated GPA for the same

Comment: As a general rule, a function like this should just return its result and not do any I/O.  Let the caller of the function decide whether and how to handle the result, including printing.

Comment: And if the caller provided multiple grades on the command line, then you want to grab the whole list:  `grades = sys.argv[1:]`

Comment: @TimRoberts - Thank you !! I was missing this factor grades = sys.argv[1:]...thank you for highlighting it..Yuppie

Answer (score 0):

no value is getting printed because the `return` statements will return the value before it will actually be able to print anything.

you must print before returning the values
Example:

```
def example(arg1):
    return None,arg1
    print("Result:",(None,arg1))
example(1)
```

it wouldn't show anything.

but if you do:

```
def functioningexample(arg1):
    print("RESULT:",(None,arg1))
    return None,arg1
fe = functioningexample(1)
print("it worked? the result Was :",fe)
```

you would get

```
>>> RESULT:(None,1)
>>> it worked? the result Was : (None,1)
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. You could have written this in the comment section as well. You should also provide a solution to it.